# Delay between two lines of code - Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint

I'm trying to make a [Simon game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28game%29).
I am mid way in programing the game but I got a problem.
I want the program to read from a QUEUE all the values that had previously been in the game and turn flash their colors in the right order (I chose to turn them gray and on second later back to normal) and this is my problem. If you look at the method `play()` you will see the comment I wrote there.  How do I do that?

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import unit4.collectionsLib.Queue;

public class window extends JPanel implements MouseListener , ActionListener{

    Queue <Integer>data = new Queue<Integer> ();
    Queue <Integer>temp = new Queue<Integer> ();
    int random;
    Timer prestart;
    int prestartcount;
    Color [] colors = {Color.red,Color.blue,Color.yellow,Color.green};  

    public window (){       
        prestart = new Timer (1000,this);
        int prestartcount=0;    
        prestart.start();       
    }

    public void play (){            
        random = (int)(Math.random()*4);
        data.insert(random);

        int x=0;
        Color temp=Color.black; 
        x = data.remove();
        this.temp.insert(x);
            temp = colors[x];
        colors[x]=Color.gray;
        // delay of one second here
        colors[x]=temp;
    }   

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(colors[0]);
        g.fillArc(80, 150, 250, 250, 0, 360);

        g.setColor(colors[1]);
        g.fillArc(80, 150, 250, 250, 0, 270);

        g.setColor(colors[2]);
        g.fillArc(80, 150, 250, 250, 0, 180);

        g.setColor(colors[3]);
        g.fillArc(80, 150, 250, 250, 0, 90);        

        g.drawString(prestartcount+"", 0, 30);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        arg0.getLocationOnScreen();     
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { 
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {      
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {     
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent act) {
        if (act.getSource()==prestart){
            if (prestartcount<3)
                prestartcount++;
            else{
                prestart.stop();
                play(); 
                }               
            }   
        }   
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use a sensible name for classes, even in test code.  Something like `SimonGameTest` might be appropriate for this. 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently. 4) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single shot Swing based [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to flip the color and call `repaint()`.  See [Using Timers in Swing Applications](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
colors[x]=Color.gray;
// delay of one second here
timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      colors[x]=temp; 
      repaint(); //repaint the gui, or you want see the effect
  }
});
timer.setInitialDelay(1000); //wait one second
timer.setRepeats(false); //only once
timer.start();
```

You may have to make temp final, or store it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Thread.sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).

```
Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Thread.sleep(1000)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) is what you need.

Comment: This will freeze the application for 1 second.

Comment: @Ishtar No, the `Play()` method is called from the Timer not the EDT :)

Comment: It's a `swing.Timer`, runs in EDT, so it will block the EDT.

Comment: @Ishtar True, sorry did not see that it is a swing timer